# trying to import CSV into phpMyAdmin

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a `.csv file` into `phpMyAdmin`.

**My table is formatted as follows:**

```
id,
staffnum,
city,
height,
eye,
hair,
titles
```

**The file is formatted as follows:**

```
"63,losangeles,5'10,green,Brown,Bartender"
"86,losangeles,5'9,blue,blonde,Bartender, Cocktail"
"263,newyork,6'1,blue,blonde,Cocktail"
"325,losangeles,5'10,brown,Brown,Bartender"
"545,newyork,6',brown,Brown,Bartender, Cocktail"
```

The issue I believe I am running into is that the positions (Bartender, Cocktail etc) are to go in to the column titles and I don't have the correct formatting. Do I need to use single quotes around values with multiple commas such as:

```
"86,losangeles,5'9,blue,blonde,'Bartender, Cocktail'"
```

Also, will the apostrophes in the height section cause issues when uploading a `CSV` file? I've search online but no one seems to have the clear set instructions on how the `CSV` file is supposed to be formatted. I have tried importing this and it says success however, no values are applied to any of the fields.

File is [here](http://www.2shared.com/file/5y_kESkh/staff.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think if your .csv file was formatted like this it would import, and the id field would autoincrement

```
'',63,losangeles,5'10,green,Brown,Bartender
'',86,losangeles,5'9,blue,blonde,Bartender, Cocktail
'',263,newyork,6'1,blue,blonde,Cocktail
'',325,losangeles,5'10,brown,Brown,Bartender
'',545,newyork,6',brown,Brown,Bartender, Cocktail
```